Let $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ be three real numbers such that $e^{3i\alpha}+e^{3i\beta}+e^{3i\gamma}+e^{i(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}=0$

Let $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$  be three real numbers such that $e^{3i\alpha}+e^{3i\beta}+e^{3i\gamma}+e^{i(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}=0$, $k=\left|e^{i\alpha}+e^{i\beta}+e^{i\gamma}\right|$. Then, $k$ can be equal to which of the following options?
(a) $1$
(b) $2$
(c) $\frac{3}{2}$
(d) $4$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

My Approach:
$e^{3i\alpha}+e^{3i\beta}+e^{3i\gamma}+e^{i(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}=0$ can be written as
$\cos(3\alpha)+\cos(3\beta)+\cos(3\gamma)+\cos(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+i\left(\sin(3\alpha)+\sin(3\beta)+\sin(3\gamma)+\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\right)=0+oi$
Hence $\cos(3\alpha)+\cos(3\beta)+\cos(3\gamma)+\cos(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)=0$ and $\left(\sin(3\alpha)+\sin(3\beta)+\sin(3\gamma)+\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\right)=0$
$\implies \cos(3\alpha)+\cos(3\beta)+\cos(3\gamma)=-\cos(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)..........(1)$
and
$\left(\sin(3\alpha)+\sin(3\beta)+\sin(3\gamma)=-\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\right)..........(2)$
squaring and adding $(1)$ and $(2)$
I obtained $\cos(3\alpha-3\beta)+\cos(3\beta-3\gamma)+\cos(3\gamma-3\alpha)=-1$
Whhich can further be simplified to obtain $4\cos^{3}(\alpha-\beta)+4\cos^{3}(\beta-\gamma)+4\cos^{3}(\gamma-\alpha)-3\cos(\alpha-\beta)-3\cos(\beta-\gamma)-3\cos(\gamma-\alpha)=-1...........(3)$
Now let's get to question asked $k==\left|e^{i\alpha}+e^{i\beta}+e^{i\gamma}\right|$
$\implies k=\sqrt{3+2\left(\cos(\alpha-\beta)+\cos(\beta-\gamma)+\cos(\gamma-\alpha)\right)}$
Now I don't know how I link $k$  with equation three to obtain range of $k$.
Help Needed.

One approach: note that it is enough to find one solution to this equation and then read off what $k$ is for that solution. For example you can try $e^{3i\alpha} = z^3$ and $e^{3i\beta} = z^3$ (i.e. $\alpha=\beta$) and then try $e^{3i\gamma} = -z^3$ and $e^{i(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)} = -z^3$ (i.e. the first two terms are equal and the last two points are also equal but point in the opposite direction). In this case $k = |z|$ and its not too hard to solve for what $z$ should be.

btw where did you get this question from ?

@its from one of Indian coaching institute

Answer is option 2 ${}{}{}$

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad it's more than one correct type questions....
